# Inherited method returning childs attributes doesnt work c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have two classes `Taxi` and `Van`. Lets say `van1` is an instance of the `Van`. Whenever I run `van1.ReturnNumOfPass()`, it doesnt work properly.

I think it returns `Taxi.num_of_pass` instead. Is there any way to fix or do I have to write override the method? Thank you in advance

```
internal class Taxi
{
    private string SPZ;
    private int num_of_pas;
    private int max_num_of_pas = 4;

    public virtual int ReturnNumOfPas() => num_of_pas;
}


internal class Van : Taxi
{
    private string SPZ;
    private int num_of_pas;
    private int max_num_of_pas = 2;  
}
```

I tried to add `this` before the `num_of_pass` when returning it

Answer (score 6):

You made `num_of_pas` as a `private` variable in each class - that means that they are independent variables.

If you want `Van` to use the same `num_of_pas` as `Taxi` then declare it as `protected` in `Taxi` and remove the declaration from `Van`. Like this:

```
internal class Taxi
{
    protected int num_of_pas = 4;

    public virtual int ReturnNumOfPas()
    {
        return num_of_pas;
    }
}

internal class Van : Taxi
{
    public Van()
    {
        num_of_pas = 8;
    }
}
```

To test this, I ran this code:

```
Van van = new();
Console.WriteLine(van.ReturnNumOfPas());
```

The result was that `8` was output to the `Console`.

---

If I were writing more idiomatic C# then I would probably have expected something like this:

```
internal class Taxi
{
    public int NumberOfPassengers { get; protected set; } = 4;
}

internal class Van : Taxi
{
    public Van()
    {
        this.NumberOfPassengers = 8;
    }
}
```

We would typically use properties to return values, not functions.